# Warning: fflush() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i need some help with this code in the install.php which has to run first before the program but it brings an error pointing on the fflush i don't know what to do please help?

```
    <?php
        fflush();

      authTableCreate();
      announceTableCreate();
      classTableCreate();
      studentTableCreate();
      classmembersTableCreate();
      attendanceTableCreate();
      assignmentTableCreate();
      messageTableCreate();
      supportTableCreate();


      if (!authCheckUserExists('admin')) { // this is their first install probably
          $randpass = 'admin' . mt_rand();
          authAddUser('admin', $randpass, 100, 100);   // create default superuser account
          announceAddAnnouncement('Welcome', 'This is the default start page for IntraSchool.  You should change this to something that describes how the system works within your school.');
    ?>  

    <p>Congratulations!  You have successfully setup <em>IntraSchool</em>.  You may now <a href="login/login.php">login</a> with the username <em>admin</em> and password <em><?=$randpass?></em>.  Please change the password to something you can remember.</p>

    <?php
      } else {
    ?>

    <p>The installation script has reinitialized any deleted tables.</p>

    <?php
      }

      page_footer();
    ?>
```

Comment: Maybe you want `flush()` and not `fflush()`?  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fflush.php

Comment: If this is the [IntraSchool CMS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/intraschool/), then you're working with a codebase that is 10 years old. You may want something that's been updated a bit more recently.

Comment: fflush() flushes to a file, and you need to pass the file resource as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fflush.php) - always a good place to start.

My understanding of your code is limited, so I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here (in particular, it looks like you're doing database operations, for which `fflush` should not be necessary). That said, here's a little background:

`fflush` flushes an open file to disk. You need to provide it with a file handle to flush.

When you're writing to a file on your disk, the operating system will often store up a bunch of your data and write it all to the disk at one time, rather than writing each byte as you send it. This is primarily for performance reasons. Sometimes, however, you need to get that data written at a particular point in your program. That's what `fflush` is for. But for `fflush` to work, you need to tell it what file you're talking about - that's the file handle mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`fflush()` requires the handle of the file to be flushed.  It is likely a typo for `flush()`, however as it's apparently at the start of the file that would do nothing at all.  You should just delete the line.

It's only a warning though, so the rest of the script has probably been executed.  If it's a once-only setup script then you probably do not need to run it again.